# how to change sql query while resizing the browser

Tags: java, php

I want to write a platform which it can load different data depends on the browser size, It is a responsive platform , I have 4 column in my mysql database , they named " mobile " , " tablet " ," sdevice " for small devices and " ldevice " for large devices, My purpose is when the client resize the browser, php change data for example from sdevice to ldevice,
I want this to be happened without refreshing the page; here is what i did,

```html
<?php
 include '../init/connect.php';
 $product_sql = "SELECT * FROM banner_text";
 $product_result = mysqli_query($conn,$product_sql);
 while ($product_row = mysqli_fetch_array($product_result)) {
    $mobile[] = $product_row['mobile'];
    $tablet[] = $product_row['tablet'];
    $sdevice[] = $product_row['sdevice'];
    $ldevice[] = $product_row['ldevice'];
 };
?>
```

```html
<div class=" text-center" style=" color: white; position: relative;">
    <img src="images/image02.jpg" alt="" style="">
    <a href="#group">
      <div class="holder" style="position: absolute; top:0;width: 100%;height:100%;">
          <div  style="margin: 10px 50px; ">
            <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 10px;">
            <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
            <div class="text-content" data-target = "1" style="margin:0 auto; width: 680px;  position: relative; top: 15px; ">
              <script type="text/javascript">
                var width = $(window).width();
                if ( width < 768) {
                  $('.text-content:eq(1)').html('<?php echo $mobile[1]?>')
                }else if(width > 768 && width < 992){
                  $('.text-content:eq(1)').html('<?php echo $tablet[1]?>')
                }else if(width > 992 && width < 1200){
                  $('.text-content:eq(1)').html('<?php echo $sdevice[1]?>')
                }else if(width > 1200){
                  $('.text-content:eq(1)').html('<?php echo $ldevice[1]?>')
                };
                $(window).resize(function() {
                  width = $(window).width();
                  console.log(width);
                  if ( width < 768) {
                    $('.text-content:eq(1)').html('<?php echo $mobile[1]?>')
                  }else if(width > 768 && width < 992){
                    $('.text-content:eq(1)').html('<?php echo $tablet[1]?>')
                  }else if(width > 992 && width < 1200){
                    $('.text-content:eq(1)').html('<?php echo $sdevice[1]?>')
                  }else if(width > 1200){
                    $('.text-content:eq(1)').html('<?php echo $ldevice[1]?>')
                  };
                });
              </script>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: @David i know this, but i need to change content , so i should change the content from server

Comment: It looks like you're already getting all the content from the server and re-sizing on `$(window).resize(function() { ... });`  Is that resize logic not working in some way?

Comment: In this case you should use AJAX.

Comment: @DawidKarasiewicz i know, and i dont know how to use it here!

Comment: @David im not able to dynamically echo the div, i have the problem with the part [ $mobile[1] ]

Comment: @David that [1] i want this 1 print dynamically

Comment: @amirchearfull: What problem is that?  What is the resulting client-side code that this creates and in what way does it fail?  `"i want this 1 print dynamically"` - What does that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use event 'resize'.

```
$(document).on('resize', function(){

...

});
```